# how to make curved wave with svg

Tags: html, svg

i am trying to make a curved wave with svg. I already have created an waterwave, but there should be at the end a second curved wave.

This is what i have now:[image]

En this is how it should look like:
[image]

How can i achieve this?

This is the code i already have:

```html
<svg class="four" viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="none">   
            <path d="M0,100 C100,200 350,0 300,100 L500,0 L0,0 Z" style="stroke: none; fill:#1e90ff;"></path>
         </svg>
```

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xodvLdsw/)?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c1zwenft/5/

Comment: Download an SVG editor such as Inkscape, or use an online editor such as [SVG-Edit](https://svg-edit.github.io/svgedit/releases/svg-edit-2.8.1/svg-editor.html) and draw what you want. Much easier than trying to do it by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of a quadratic Bézier curve in the last bit of your `path` like this:

> ```
> <path d="M0,100 C150,200 350,0 300,100 Q400,25 500,25 L500,0 L0,0 Z" 
> style="stroke: none; fill:#1e90ff;"></path>
> </svg>
> ```